# webpack-dev-server with ExtractTextPlugin does not generate css of scss file

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

I already read SO damn much tutorials, tickets etc, and i just cannot resolve it... 
I have a React project with webpack. And i try to use .scss files for styling.
So i have this webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./src"
    },
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/app'
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            //Babel
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"],
                }
            },
            //Sass
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('src/style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],
    debug: true
};
```

And a `App.scss`File in `src/`:

```
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: pink;
}

h2 {
  color: greenyellow;
}
```

Than in my `index.html` I include the css file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Aline</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="../app.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Than i call `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --quiet`.
Than chrome always tells me it cannot find the css file, and it seems webpack just doesnt care about my scss file....

my package.json dependencies would be:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.11.6",
    "css-loader": "0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "3.10.1",
    "sass-loader": "4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "webpack": "1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Got the answer on Twitter by a webpack develeoper itself! It was my own stupidity. I am still learning about webpack etc, and I forgot how webpack is working.
It builds a tree out of dependencies, so logically it needs know the scss files in some way... so i told my enter point (app.js) per require about my scss file, and TADA. There it goes. 
I havent thought about that, because all the tutorials using the ExtractTextPlugin explain it collects all the scss files and makes a single css out of it. So I was like "oh it collects all my scss files out of my folders. Nice!" But yeah... nah xD it collects it from the tree not the disk :p